# Notepad++ Alternate Row/Background Color

Tags: logging, editor, notepad++

Can Notepad++ be made to alternate row background colors?  I often have to examine CSV and other log files before they get fed into Python or Matlab, and it would be much easier to keep track of long lines if even lines had one background color and odd lines another, e.g. http://blog.marcnuri.com/blog/default/2007/03/15/JTable-Row-Alternate-Row-Background .

Comment: http://tournasdimitrios1.wordpress.com/2011/11/13/improving-notepad-by-custom-themes/

Comment: I've played with the styles, but didn't find a way to set alternating line colors.  Did I miss a setting?

Comment: FWIW the Zeus editor has that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be beneficial to have functionality you described present in Notepad++ but currently there is nothing like that implemented. You can leave a **feature request** following the link with the same name on [Notepad++ website](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/contribute/).